# nw-builder - usage instructions

Tags: windows, command-line, node-webkit, nw.js

I am using Node Webkit to create desktop app.  I now need to create a single executable file so have installed the following: https://github.com/nwjs/nw-builder

I am struggling understanding the instructions, especially the command line stuff.  The documentation states the below:

> Usage: nwbuild [options] [path]
>
> Options:   -p, --platforms      Platforms to build, comma-sperated,
>   can be: win32,win64,osx32,osx64,linux32,linux64   ['osx32', 'osx64',
>   'win32', 'win64']   -v, --version        The nw version, eg. 0.8.4
>   [default: "latest"]   -r, --run            Runs NW.js for the current
>   platform                                   [default: false]   -o,
>   --buildDir       The build folder                                                      [default: "./build"]   -f, --forceDownload  Force download of NW.js
>   [default: false]   --cacheDir           The cache folder   --quiet
>   Disables logging
>   [default: false]

I have two folders, one containing the app files and the package.json, the other folder containing all the NW files. I have also created a third folder that merges the these two folders and where I have changed the .zip file of the app to a .nw file.

Where do I run the buildDir command from?

and what would the exact command be? I have tried the below commands:

```
nwbuild -o build

nwbuild --buildDir /build

nwbuild -o, --buildDir /build
```

but all come back showing the above usage info and none of the folders contain a /build/ folder

Can anyone please help?  Many thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to set the `buildDir`, just pass in the path like this:

```
nwbuild -p win64 <PATH TO APP FILES>
```

The options are all *optional*, so you don't need to set any if you don't want. You can change the build platform that I set in the example if you prefer.

Comment: Hey,Sorry for the late response.  I ran the command and it created a build folder. However, isnt it supposed to create a single executable file instead of creating a new folder with all the files?  I can already do that  without using nw-builder.  What is the purpose of nw-builder exactly?

Comment: Wasn't an `app.nw` file created? According to the docs, it should be in your build directory.

Comment: The first few lines of the [README](https://github.com/nwjs/nw-builder/blob/master/README.md) - "It will download the prebuilt binaries for a newest version, unpacks it, creates a release folder, create the app.nw file for a specified directory and copies the app.nw file where it belongs."

Comment: I get this error: the term 'nwbuild' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.